# Symfony 2.7 changes only visible after page refresh

Tags: forms, symfony, message

When the user edits data on edit_form (for example) and then click the submit button, he's redirected to the page, where the changes should be visible.

```
public function updateAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entity = $em->getRepository('ClientBundle:Client')->find($id);

    $kdnr = $entity->getKdnr();

    if (!$entity) {
      throw $this->createNotFoundException($this->get('translator')->trans('client.messages.notfound'));
    }

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
    $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    $entity->setKdnr($kdnr);

    if ($editForm->isValid()) {
        $em->flush();
        $this->getRequest()->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('notice', $this->get('translator')->trans('messages.savenotice'));
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('client_show', array('id' => $id)));
    }

    return $this->render('ClientBundle:Client:edit.html.twig', array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```

After that the message is visible, but the changes are only visible after refreshing the page. And the message only disappears after page refresh. When I leave the view and visit it again the message is still there.

Is it possible that the changes are directly visible after form submission and the message only shown up one time? Is it a session problem?

Comment: Did you set any cache headers? Try using the Browser Console to check your request and response headers.

Comment: could you show us all your action in your controller ? because it's not normal !

Comment: I edit my question, hope it helps. I don't set any cache headers and twig caching is also disabled. I tested different browser to be sure, that it's not a browser problem, but it doesn't make any difference. Maybe it could help to get tips where the error may come from. When I click in edit button again the form is filled with old data and when I refresh the page, data is right.

Comment: Add `client_show` action

Comment: In my client_show action there is nothing special (no messages, nothing is set, only clean output). The only thing I do is output the message in twig template. And the error is on the whole page, not only in this action.